# Golang gRPC Client connecting to GKE

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, grpc, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to deploy gRPC on GKE, and I followed this tutorial - https://cloud.google.com/solutions/exposing-grpc-services-on-gke-using-envoy-proxy

I got through everything, but I do not seem to be able to run gRPC on golang, while I am able to run it on grpcurl.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it after exploring the inner workings of grpcurl. For anyone who might ever be stuck, here's the difference...

```
// Not working...
conn, err = grpc.Dial(host, grpc.WithInsecure())

// Working...
var tlsConf tls.Config
tlsConf.InsecureSkipVerify = true
var creds = credentials.NewTLS(&tlsConf)
conn, err = grpc.Dial(host, grpc.WithTransportCredentials(creds))
```

Previously I used the flag `grpc.WithInsecure()`. It didn't work, so exploring grpcurl, I found that they were using `grpc.WithTransportCredentials()` instead, with `tls.Config`, setting `InsecureSkipVerify` to true instead. That turned out well.